# How can I call a function within HTML tags inside a content editable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

Why can I call myFunction() onkeyup with this html:

```
<div contenteditable="true" onkeyup="myFunction()" >A function is triggered when the user is pressing a key in the input field.</div>
```

But I can't do it using this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">A function is <span onkeyup="myFunction()" >triggered</span> when the user is pressing a key in the input field.</div>
```

In the second, I'm trying to call it only over a specific word, `triggered`, and I'm not sure what the difference is.  Thanks.

Check out the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wTy3C/4/)

Comment: @GSiry `b` is an HTML element actually... and don't post w3schools links.

Comment: @GSiry ^^ This, and the same site actually contradicts what you say and states that you *can* use keyboard events with a `b` element... http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_b.asp

Comment: Look http://jsfiddle.net/wTy3C/1/ I used spans and div without b and it still didn't work

Comment: The tag in question is not capturing keyboard events, unless you specify it as editable... http://jsfiddle.net/wTy3C/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

HTML (note that you have to set contenteditable on the span, not the parent paragraph, and it cannot be both):

```
<p>A function is <span class="bold" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="myFunction()" >triggered</span> when the user is pressing a key in the input field.</p>

<p contenteditable="true" onkeyup="myFunction()" >A function is triggered when the user is pressing a key in the input field.</p>

<div id='foo'>Not Yet</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wTy3C/2/